# variations for indicating "performed payment"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

If we need to say(write) that "some program procedure checks if an advance payment has been performed". 
What would be the "best choice" in terms of most usable and preferable verbs for such case ("performed", "entered" or "received")? 
The payment, in this case, is "almost" completed action : the payer's bank has released the funds but the executing agency hasn't received the funds as yet 
 Thanks.

Comment: @Lawrence, added some explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest word to use is *made*.

> The payment has been made.

However, when a payment has been made, it may still take a while for the other party to get it in his bank account. When he gets it, he will then say

> The payment has been received.

Comment: thanks, and if I used the phrase " ... payment has been performed" or "... payment has been entered" in official correspondence, would it be wrong or strange(weird) for perception?

Comment: Yes, it would sound weird. If you want an "official" sounding word, use **"tendered"**.